# Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

For mathematics, is it ever disadvantageous to use `\left(`  and `\right)`  in equations?

I can't see any way that doing this would hinder the typesetting, so why isn't `()` just converted into `\left(` `\right)` automatically? This would save a lot of typing.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!] A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: See [Macro for \left( and \right)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58641/22413)

Comment: see [Automatic left and right commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742) and ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773) and [Spacing around left and right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right/)/, for example

Comment: For *mathematics*... no. For *typography*, maybe; I'm sure some like it, while other go without it happily.

Comment: I'd say most use of left right in text mode math ends up being too large. Try fx `\left(x^2\right)`, this often ends up disturbing the line height.

Comment: I tend to use the rile that it should be clear what is fenced in, but at the same time the fences should **not** end up dominating the expression. In Przemysławs first example below, try writing a summation limit in two or more lines and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I'd rephrase this question "is it ever *good* to use `\left` and `\right`?".  I never do; there are maybe two sizes of enlarged delimiters worth using (`\big` and `\bigg`, for disambiguating nested parentheses, and surrounding large symbols like sums, respectively) and neither one is correctly caught by the automatic sizing.  Not to mention all the problems given by David Carlisle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of any of these?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses?lq=1
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-big-and-bigl?lq=1
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right?lq=1

Comment: Probably related to:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31526/macro-for-left-and-right

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The automatic sized braces are not always the sizes you would choose manually, but that's a matter of personal taste (and the sizes chosen by the automatic algorithm can be adjusted with the `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` parameters).

More immediate problems are that `\left( ... \right)` differs from `( ... )` even if the standard small delimiter size is chosen.

- It is a `\mathinner` atom so it gets additional spacing in many
  contexts.
- It is a `\mathinner` atom so can not be broken across lines in a math display such as `align`.
- It is a `\mathinner` atom so will not allow automatic linebreaking in inline math.
- It is a `\mathinner` atom so forms a box set to its natural length and white space around relations or added explicitly  will not be allowed to stretch or shrink to help with line breaking.
- It is a `\mathinner` atom.

Comment: Your bullets all say "it", but it's not clear to me whether your pronoun is referencing `\left( ... \right(` or `( ... )`, or something else (singular), since they are plural.

Comment: @TravisBemrose the construct `\left( stuff \right)` makes a _single_ math atom in the same way that `\mbox{ stuff}` makes a single box.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, why?? I can understand vim users downvoting my emacs answers, but I'm a bit bemused by this one.

Comment: Maybe good to note that you can circumvent the points about line breaking with pairing `\right.` and `\left.` (i.e. empty delimiters).

Comment: @morbusg but then the delimiters aren't the same size which negates most of the point of using left...right

Comment: This is perhaps the most concrete justification for the dislike of `\left...\right` I've seen. It carries far more weight than mere aesthetic opinion, which necessarily varies from person to person.

Answer (score 51):

You ask:

> For [mathematical typography], is it ever disadvantageous to use `\left(` and `\right)` in equations?

Excerpting from pp. 148f. of the TeXbook (emphasis added):

> At this point you are probably wondering why you should bother learning about `\bigl` and `\bigr` and their relatives, when `\left` and `\right` are there to calculate sizes for you automatically. Well, it's true that `\left` and `\right` are quite handy, but there are *at least three situations* in which you will want to use your own wisdom when selecting the proper delimiter size: (1) Sometimes `\left` and `\right` choose a smaller delimiter size than you want. [...] (2) Sometimes `\left` and `\right` choose a larger delimiter than you want. [...] (3) Sometimes you need to break a huge displayed formula into two or more lines, and you want to make sure that its opening and closing delimiters have the same size; but you can't use `\left` on the first line and `\right` on the last, since `\left` and `\right` must occur in pairs. [...]

To illustrate the first two cases, consider the following two examples. They contrast indiscriminate use of `\left` and `\right` with judicious use of `\big` and `\bigg`.

- Here's a case where `\left( ... \right)` produce parentheses that *aren't big enough*:

  ```
  $\left(\left(a+b\right) \left(c+d\right)\right)$ vs.\ $\bigl((a+b)(c+d)\bigr)$
  ```

[image]

- And here's a case where `\left( ... \right)` produce parentheses that are *too big* from a typographic point of view:

  ```
  $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^2}\right)^2 \mbox{ vs.\ } 
   \biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^2}\biggr)^{\!2}$
  ```

[image]

Note that the second expression not only employs `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` but also uses a *positive thinspace* after the opening parenthesis and a *negative thinspace* to position the exponent `2`. Incidentally, the recommendation to use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` in this case instead of `\left(` and `\right)` isn't just my personal preference; it's also given on p. 149 of the TeXbook.

- *Even if* the size of the parentheses produced by `\left( ... \right)` happens to be correct, the *spacing* around the large parentheses may not only be suboptimal from a purely typographic/aesthetic point of view but actually interfere with the normal interpretation of some standard operators. Consider, for instance, the following expression (culled from a recent posting to this site; I won't say *which* posting as I don't mean to single out any one person in particular):

[image]

In the first row, `\left` and `\right` are used to size the square brackets. Because `\left[` inserts a bit of extra whitespace to its immediate left, the enlarged space after `\pm` makes it look like it *might* be a *binary* operator; the reader may thus be puzzled by how one is supposed to add a `\sum` symbol and a term in square brackets -- before concluding that `\pm` is a *unary* operator and that what the author *intended to say* is that the sum is taken over the positive and negative values of the term in square brackets... By using `\bigl[` (see the look in the second row), such ambiguity doesn't arise to begin with.

---

There are still further reasons for not using `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately. See, e.g., the answer by David Carlisle for reasons related to (i) a lack of intelligent spacing *inside* a `\left...\right` pair and (ii) inability to let TeX find a *line break* within a `\left...\right` pair that's used in inline math mode.

Comment: Your `((a+b)(c+d))` is the first example I've seen where `\left( ... \right)` didn't chose the sizing I'd want it to.  Even in the second example, I prefer it over `\biggl( ... \bigr)` because they leave the `i=1` hanging out, making it look like it's not part of the expression, or like it may "fall away".

Comment: @TravisBemrose - Good typography is characterized by *balance*, meaning that no one element dominates the others. Whereas the `\left(...\right)` approach does ensure that the material is fully enclosed, the resulting very large parentheses tend to *dominate* the enclosed material. The `\biggl(...\biggr)` approach tries to strike a balance: both the parentheses *and* the material they enclose are given roughly equal visual importance. And do ask yourself: what's the risk that a reader might think that "i=1" isn't part of the expression, just because it's not "fully enclosed" by the parentheses?

Comment: Yes, larger has drawbacks.  On your last point, I wasn't trying to imply that it wouldn't be clear or the reader wouldn't understand.  I was indicating that the part of my brain that deals with a physical 3D world, distracts the part of my brain that deals with abstract equations.  I can read the first faster. Internal conflict or at least multi-tasking slows down my ability to process the second. Not to a snails pace certainly, but "slightly longer" when you're talking about sub-second timing can mean ~1.5 - 3 times longer.

Comment: This strikes me as damning by faint praise. If the worst thing that could happen is the parentheses are just a millimeter too large on `((a+b)(c+d))`, it seems like always using `\left` and `\right` is a good heuristic that will rarely, if ever, be a problem.

Comment: @ClosedLimelikeCurves - Not sure I understand your comment. What part of my answer is your inference that "the worst thing that could happen [with an indiscriminate use of `\left` and `\right`] is the parentheses are just a millimeter too large" based on?

Answer (score 35):

Here's an example: in the first display, `\left` and `\right` are used throughout, while in the second several manual adjustments have been made in order to properly typeset the formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{t}\right)^{tn}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{r}{t}\right)^{t}\right)^{n}=
\left(\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{t}\right)^{t}\right)^{n}=
\left(e^{r}\right)^{n}=
e^{rn}
\]
\[
\lim_{t\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac{r}{t}\Bigr)^{\!tn}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\Bigl(\!\Bigl(1+\frac{r}{t}\Bigr)^{\!t\,}\Bigr)^{\!n}=
\Bigl(\,\lim_{t\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac{r}{t}\Bigr)^{\!t\,}\Bigr)^{\!n}=(e^r)^n=
e^{rn}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no doubt whatsoever that the second version is better: it's more readable and less distracting. Yes, it requires some labor, but let me remind what [τέχνη (techne) means](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=te/xnh):

> τέχν-η , ἡ, (τέκτων)
>   A. *art, skill, cunning of hand*, esp. in metalworking, Od.3.433, 6.234, 11.614; also of a shipwright, Il.3.61; of a soothsayer, A.Ag.249 (pl., lyr.), Eu.17, S.OT389, etc.; “τέχναι ἑτέρων ἕτεραι” Pi.N.1.25; “ὤπασε τ. πᾶσαν” Id.O.7.50.
>   2​. *craft, cunning*, in bad sense, δολίη τ. Od.4.455, Hes.Th.160: pl., arts, wiles, Od.8.327.332, Hes.Th.496,929; “δολίαις τέχναισι χρησάμενος” Pi.N.4.58; τέχναις τινός by his arts (or simply by his agency), Id.O.9.52, P.3.11; τέχνην κακὴν ἔχει he has a bad trick, Hes.Th.770, cf. Pi.I.4(3).35(53), S Ph.88, etc.
>   3​. *way, manner, or means whereby a thing is gained*, without any definite sense of art or craft, μηδεμιῇ τ. in no wise, Hdt.1.112; ἰθέῃ τ. straightway, Id.9.57; πάσῃ τ. by all means, Ar.Nu.1323, Th.65, Ec.366; παντοίᾳ τ. S.Aj.752, etc.; “οὐκ ἀποστήσομαι . . οὔτε τ. οὔτε μηχανῇ οὐδεμιᾷ” IG12.39.22; “πάσῃ τ. καὶ μηχανῇ” X.An.4.5.16; “μήτε τ. μήτε μηχανῇ μηδεμιᾷ” Lys.13.95.
>
> […]
>
> <sub>Henry George Liddell. Robert Scott. A Greek-English Lexicon. revised and augmented throughout by. Sir Henry Stuart Jones. with the assistance of. Roderick McKenzie. Oxford. Clarendon Press. 1940.</sub>

Another example, where the box is artificially spread out in order to emulate a line of type where interword spaces are enlarged for justification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Not too much spread:

\makebox[\dimexpr\width+1pc][s]{Text $y-y_0=m\left(x-x_0\right)$ and other text}

\makebox[\dimexpr\width+1pc][s]{Text $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ and other text}

\medskip

Larger spread:

\makebox[\dimexpr\width+2pc][s]{Text $y-y_0=m\left(x-x_0\right)$ and other text}

\makebox[\dimexpr\width+2pc][s]{Text $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ and other text}

\end{document}
```

The lines with `\left` and `\right` are wider because of the added space around `\left` and `\right`; in those lines the spaces around the minus sign in `x-x_0` don't stretch, because `\left(...\right)` makes a subformula with rigid spaces. The effect is more evident in the second pair of lines. Note that the delimiters are not bigger (and they shouldn't be anyway, in this case).

[image]

Typography is not just laying down letters, but it's also a craft and, in some cases (not this one, of course), art. As such we can't think that any automated system will be able to avoid human judgment.

TeX allows automation, with a not so bad output; if we want our documents to be good, we have to work on them. A good document is not to be hung on museums' walls, but read by people: the fewer distractions, the easier will be reading it.

Comment: +1 for "As such we can't think that any automated system will be able to avoid human judgment".

Comment: I find the 2nd one to be distracting, and much prefer the first.

Comment: @TravisBemrose Yes that's interesting... I also prefer the first. I find it helpful when the outer parentheses are larger than the inner ones so that nesting is clear.

Comment: @TravisBemrose Everybody is entitled their own opinions. :-) Increasing the size of the parentheses places superscripts in almost random positions, while they are conceptually at the same level: `$(a^{x})^{y}=a^{xy}$`

Comment: Yes. :-)  I take your point that conceptually they are at the same level, but they're not being *applied* the same.  If there's a reason to use parentheses to place them at different levels (as in the example), I find it a mental assist to emphasize the separation of the operations.  It also helps me pair-match quickly, when each pair is a different size. And lastly, I find the way the `t` exponent sticks out of the outer parenthesis unaesthetic. (And the way the inner `t` hangs out of the bottom of its own parentheses, but that's not worth the effort, so I breathe and move on.)

Answer (score 11):

There are many reasons. The simplest one is of an aesthetic nature (edited according to some suggestions from the comments):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Is:
\[
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\right)^2=\frac{\pi^4}{36}
\]
Should be:
\[
\Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)^2=\frac{\pi^4}{36}
\]
or 
\[
\biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\biggr)^2=\frac{\pi^4}{36}
\]
(with some addidional corrections  after the opening parenthesis).

\end{document}
```

[image]

The braces choosen in the first example are too big and should be corrected.

If an equation is splitted into many lines, there are no matching `\left` or `\right`.

Comment: I actually think the first example looks nicer, because it contains the whole summation...

Comment: @user50612 But one of typographic rules (I am not sure, if in all countries) says, that the braces should be approximately as big as the summation sign (here), but without its limits.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke, That's not universal, at least. Swedish _Almqvist & Wiksells sättningsregler_ (Lansburgh 1961, p. 261) would prefer the first example (but smaller parens if there would have been only a subscript, but no superscript to the summation symbol).

Comment: The first example is more readable, both must be corrected: the exponant 2 is to far right and the = is not balanced.

Comment: I'd use `\biggl` and `\biggr` in that case; with `\Bigl` the parenthesis is too short (a `\,` after the opening parenthesis could improve). For the exponent, `^{\!2}` is recommended, in order to compensate for the curved shape of the closing parenthesis.

Comment: @pst - Believe it or not, but not everyone has easy access to a copy of Lansburgh (1961). Is it available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico No, very few have access to it. That's why I took care to write about what it said instead of just linking somewhere. Few who read my comment would even know of this work beforehand, but I think many will realize that there are not that many books with such detailed rules for compositors, that they differ between when a summation sign has only subscript or both subscript and superscript.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke But rules are not laws, and they're just made up by someone.  I find the first natural and graceful.  The second clunky and distracting.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke - I would like to suggest that you update your answer to show both `\bigg` and `\Big` parents as alternatives to `\left`/`\right`.

Comment: @Mico Updated, with a comment.

Comment: ```\left``` and ```\right``` across line-breaks can be accomplished thus: ```… \right. \\ \left. …```. Of course, you have to keep track of the number of ```\left…``` so you may need to add multiple ```\right.``` before, and multiple ```\left.``` after ```\\```. You can avoid all of this with ```\big``` etc., but it appears to me to be insufficiently appreciated that, automatic sizing aside, with ```\left``` and ```\right``` you cannot forget to close an opened parenthesis/bracket/brace if you use them consistently.

Comment: @PointedEars And in this case you can obtain left and right parentheses of different heights.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Please give an example because I was not able to produce that unwanted result yet.