# Is possible to make every "(...)" into "\left(...\right)" over all document?

Tags: delimiters, size, parenthesis, parentheses

It is a quite simple question.

I use mathematical symbols a lot, so, every time I need to keep typing $\left(...\right)$, or $\left{...\right}$ etc (that sucks :P ).

I know I can make a new command in such a way these commands become shorter. But is there a way of declaring something at the preamble and the parenthesis adjust their size automatically throughout the whole document, a package, whatever, anything like this? (AT LEAST in math mode!)

Thank you, guys!

Comment: are you _sure_ you need that many `\left` `\right`? it is usually best to avoid them  (we have several answers on site about that)

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/

Comment: Alternatively: look at your editor, many have features to make inserting such sequences easier.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Isn't this a matter of taste? :P

Comment: @AndersonFelipeViveiros in a sense everything is, but the spacing around left right  is only ever suitable for large constructs such as arrays it would certainly be a mis-use of the system to have `$f\left(x\right)$` left-right affects the horizontal spacing even when the brackets don't stretch. Obviously anyone may prefer any typeset result that they wish but  tex was not designed to produce such a result by default.

Comment: but yes it is possible:-) (`{\catcode\`\(\active\gdef({\left\lparen}}\mathcode\`\(="8000` for example.