# Writing a text side by side an equation in \align environment

Tags: equations

I have a very long equation in `\align*` environment so that I split it into two lines as shown in the screenshot blew

[image]

I want to write some text side to side the above part of the equation using `&&\text{}` ,but Latex throw it away in the margins and I do not know why this happens. Here is my code regarding this part :

```
\begin{align*}
X_{p}\psi &=  
X_p\bigl( \psi(p) \bigr) 
 + \sum_i \left(\left.\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x^{i}}\right|_{p} \right) X_{p}\left(x^{i}-a^{i}\right)           &&\text{(plaplapla)} \\
&\phantom{{}= }+ \sum_i \sum_j X_{p}\left( \left(\zeta_{ij}\circ\phi \right)\left(x^{i}-a^{i}\right)\left(x^{j}-a^{j} \right) \right) .
```

The first `&` is using for aligning equations later, any my preamble just has the necessary packages for mathematics.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue you're experiencing (...the text being pushed into the margin). Can you elaborate?

Comment: I’ve deleted my answer since I realized that it was a completely wrong solution for a nonexistent problem… :-)

Comment: Your code doesn't feature a `&&\text{}` portion. Please fix.

Comment: I fixed it @Mico

Comment: @HusseinEid: ...there still isn't any evidence that the text is "thrown away into the margin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the explanatory text string isn't all that long, it should be enough to separate it from the other material in the first row with a `\quad` or `\qquad` directive.

I would also like to recommend strongly that you get rid of the habit of using `\left` and `\right` with all math-mode parentheses. See, e.g., [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) for more information on this subject.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule % Just to illustrate the width of the text block -- feel free to omit!
\begin{align*}
X_{p}\psi &= X_p\bigl( \psi(p) \bigr) 
  +\sum_i \biggl(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x^{i}}\biggr|_{p}\,\biggr) X_{p}(x^{i}-a^{i}) 
  \qquad\text{some explanatory thoughts}\\
&\quad+ \sum_i \sum_j X_{p}\bigl( (\zeta_{ij}\circ\phi)(x^{i}-a^{i})(x^{j}-a^{j}) \bigr) .
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible solutions to this problem, depending both on the real equations and the real hints, and also on the page layout. It's easier if you load the `geometry` package, because the default horizontal margins with geometry are much more sensible. Second, you can use for the second line (without hint) the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`, so don't load the latter). `alignat` would let you control the horizontal spacing between equation and hints.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  X_{p}ψ&=
  X_p\bigl( ψ(p) \bigr)
  + ∑_i \left(\left.\frac{∂ ψ}{∂ xⁱ}\right|_{p} \right) X_{p}\left(xⁱ-aⁱ\right) &   & \text{some more or less long hint} \\
  &\phantom{{}= }+ ∑_i ∑_j \mathrlap{X_{p}\left( \left(\zeta_{ij} ∘ \phi \right)\left(xⁱ-aⁱ\right)\left(x^{j}-a^{j} \right) \right)+A+B.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is not preferable of course. It is horrible to show the frames. Is there an alternative solution ?

Comment: @HusseinEid - Have you *looked* at Bernard's code? Have you figured out what the `showframe` option does -- and that it's entirely possible to omit this option?

Comment: The only difference between this code and my code is the `showframe` option which creates a frame for every page.  @Mico

Comment: @HusseinEid - Did you notice the `&   & \text{some more or less long hint}` part? It's not in your posting...

Comment: No, it exists .. see my code again. @Mico

Comment: It exists… now, not when I answered. More seriously, the real important different is the use of `\mathrlap` for the hint, which allows the hint column to overlap the end of the first column (to some extent. I've updated the code, changing the equation to make that more apparent. As to the `showframe`option, it is there only to visualize  the hint does not go into the margin.