# \left(\check h\right) vs. \left(\hat h\right)

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, scaling, size

The sizes of the parentheses in the example below do not scale nicely. Compiling the code

```
%\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % doesn't help.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mleftright}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % With newtx and pdflatex, everything is equally bombastic.
\begin{document}
\(\left(\check h\right)\)
\(\left(\hat h\right)\)
\(\mleft(\check h\mright)\)
\(\mleft(\hat h\mright)\)
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` results in [image: PDF result]

The red lines are drawn afterwards for clarity. Note that although the circumflex and the caron have only slightly different placements and sizes (which may or may not be justified), the differences in the sizes of scaled parentheses are overwhelming. This negatively affect mathematical texts where both ĥ and ȟ are used inside scaled parentheses.

With the newtx family and `pdflatex`, the parentheses are simply bombastically large, but at least equally large. The (subjectively) best results are achieved when running `pslatex` on the above code (using newtx or not): the parentheses are moderately large and equal in size. Is there any way out for Computer Modern fonts and `pdflatex`?

Comment: here (as often) it is better to take control and use `\bigl(...\bigr)` rather than `\left(..\right)` (or in this case simply `(..)` as egreg observes

Comment: There's a reason why I recommend using `\left` and `\right` very sparingly. Note that `$(\hat{h})$` has perfectly sized brackets.

Comment: @LeonMeier you can tweak the font parameters and/or `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` to get the brackets the same size in this case but `\left` right have mostly unwanted effect on horizontal space as well and it has to be said, it isn't TeX's best feature.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740

Comment: @LeonMeier What David and egreg said is right. I have had the same experience before. Sometimes it is better to manually determine the bracket size and sometimes it is better to use `\left` and `\right`. Type the following in your LaTeX document to see the scales in ascending order: `\[   ( \quad \big( \quad \Big( \quad \bigg( \quad \Bigg( \]`

Comment: @LeonMeier If I look at my 200 page lecture notes on calculus, I find `\left` and `\right` only used when they contain fractions (except for a couple of arrays and the absolute value of an integral); `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` are used for integral evaluation; `\bigl` and `\bigr` appear sporadically. There's generally *no* need to adapt the size of the fences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go slowly. Here's a better comparison (note that `mleftright` is only about fixing the horizontal spacing and does nothing different from using `\left` and `\right` as far as choosing a size is concerned).

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % With newtx and pdflatex, everything is equally bombastic.

\begin{document}

\(\left(\check{h}\right)\)
\( (\check{h}) \)
\( \bigl(\check{h}\bigr) \)
\( \Bigl(\check{h}\Bigr) \)

\(\left(\hat{h}\right)\)
\( (\hat{h}) \)
\( \bigl(\hat{h}\bigr) \)
\( \Bigl(\hat{h}\Bigr) \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

The tiny difference in height of `\hat` with respect to `\check` forces `\left` and `\right` to choose the next level in the latter case.

Parentheses are only available at discrete steps: normal, `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`. The rules are fairly complicated: there is an interplay of two parameters, `\delimitershortfall` (a dimension) and `\delimiterfactor`; the usual values are 5pt for the former (a length) and 901 for the latter (an integer).

If *y*<sub>1</sub> and *y*<sub>2</sub> denote the height and depth of the material to cover, TeX sets *y* to twice the maximum of the two lengths. If *f* is the value of `\delimiterfactor` and *d* the size of `\delimitershortfall`, then TeX chooses a delimiter whose (total) size is at least *fy*/1000 and at least *y*–*d*. It's here that the difference in height between `\hat` and `\check` comes into play, together with the fact that *h* is tall. Note that *at least* is the key: a tiny difference may cause the choice to jump to the next available size. In this case the difference is slightly less than 0.66pt (0.22mm); the value of *y* is 17.84726pt for `\check{h}` and 19.16668pt for `\hat{h}`, so we have that the fences should be at least 16.08038pt for `\check{h}` and 17.26918pt for `\hat{h}`: the tiny difference becomes about 1.2pt when the choice of the fences is attempted, which is indeed quite big (the height of *h* is the main factor).

With *a* instead, we'd get

[image]

There's generally no need that the fences cover all the material between them and that's the purpose of the two parameters described above. The availability of fences only at discrete steps is, of course, of hindrance and often the chosen size is too big.

If you look at `\( (\hat{h}) \)`, you see it’s the right size. Maybe `\big` size could be a choice, but if you look carefully, the fences extend too much below the baseline. Good typography is a craft and requires judgement: automatisms are evil.

Comment: @LeonMeier Not that I know; as I said, the problem is that fences are only available at discrete steps (unless we're beyond `\Bigg`).