# \left( adds space

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Why `$f\left(x\right)$` adds a space between *f* and the opening parenthesis while `$f(x)$` does not? Is the space anyhow *more correct* typesetting for a function? If not, is there a way to remove the space added by `\left(` or prevent it from appearing?

This came as a huge surprise to me. Sorry if it is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
$f\left(x\right)$

$f(x)$
\end{document}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: `\left` adds a space by design (in most cases). Don't use it for function parentheses, it looks ugly

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740

Comment: Why are you writing `f\left(x\right)` in the first place?

Comment: Maybe I should delete the question now that I see the linked ones, but I still feel this is more specific. As a not-too-skilled user I thought the spacing had some meaningful reason and could be necessary for functions, too.

Comment: @Mico I was actually writing a command: `\f{}`, so I wanted the parentheses to be flexible. This was lost when writing the minimal example