# Big symbol "|" in latex

Tags: symbols

I need to use | with the mean of "such that". It's in an expression with fraction and so I need to have a big |. I've tried to use \displaystyle before | but it doesn't work. Putting \left before | work, but Texstudio give an error because there isn't any \right. What can I do?

Comment: you can always size it with an wxplicit size.  `\bigg` might be appropriate.

Comment: Please accept an answer if you have found a solution. By the way, I would recommend zyy's answer, as this will scale with the content!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following

```latex
\begin{equation}
\left. \frac{\partial f \left( x , y \right)}{\partial x} \right|_{x = 0}
\end{equation}
```

This will yield

[image: 437265]

Comment: What's the purpose of writing `f \left( x , y \right)` instead of, say, `f(x,y)`? Put differently, why make (La)TeX insert whitespace between `f` and `(`?

Comment: @Mico LaTeX just recognize `\left( \right)` as occupying more space, I kind of have the habit of using `\left( \right)` instead of `( )` for all situation so that my document is more consistent.

Comment: "...so that my document is more consistent." You know what Ralph Waldo Emerson had to say about consistency, right? If not, here goes: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines. With consistency a great soul has simply nothing to do. He may as well concern himself with his shadow on the wall." (excerpt from an essay, entitled "Self-Reliance") Ouch! :-)

Comment: @Mico Hey! It does take me some effort to make sense of this quote! It is true that we should think out of the box, but it is also not bad to keep some idea while you not yet getting a new one!

Comment: In case you're still not convinced that using `\left` and `\right` for the sake of consistency is maybe not all that great an idea, do check out the posting [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001)

Comment: @Mico Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

I find the ‘middle’ commands look better for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \[
\left.\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}\right| f(t) = t^2 + 1
 \]%
    \[
 \frac{\partial f( x, y)}{\partial x}\biggm| f(t) = t^2 + 1
 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want only a left delimiter but not a right one, you can use `\left|  \right.` (with a dot).

Answer (score 1):

Using a specific package called `diffcoeff` (https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.pdf) you can obtain the same result. It is not a classic command but it is very simple to understand. The `\diffdef{pvrule}{op-symbol=\partial}` is a macro for to write a `partial` symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\diffdef{pvrule}{op-symbol=\partial}

\begin{document}
\[\diff.pvrule.{f(x,y)}x[x=0]\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addendum:

You can use a similar code for the function of one variable using the character `$d$`: see the macro `op-symbol=d`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\diffdef{pvrule}{op-symbol=d}

\begin{document}
\[\diff.pvrule.{(x^2+3x)}x[x=1]=5\]
\end{document}
```

[image]