# Is there any way to make \right) appear right after I type \left(?

Tags: texmaker, editors, auto-completion

Similar to how when you type `\begin{document}`, 
`\end{document}` automatically appears.

This is for TexMaker.

Comment: Hello, in which sourcecode editor?

Comment: @boycott.se-yo' I see the boycott is going well. :)

Comment: @boycott.se-yo' TexMaker

Comment: `\left( ... \right)` has many legitimate uses and even if you only use it a handful of times in a document, typing out the whole thing can be tedious and autocompleting `\right)` would be a handy and desirable feature even if it only got used once per document. However, the fact you're asking this question makes me a *teeny tiny* bit worried you may be overusing `\left( ... \right)` a common beginner's error that I probably still make. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Au101 I probably am. However, I am just using LaTex for homework assignments and lecture notes so I am not _that_ concerned with having perfect spacing.

Comment: @Mohammed_Shahid: I really don't know how this can be achieved in `texmaker`, but I would recommend you the editor `TexStudio` – autocompetiton and many other features are included …

Comment: @user49915 hmm, okay. Can you give me some examples of \left and \right resulting in this poor type set? I believe you, but in my limited experience it has never been that bad so I am curious to see how bad it can get.

Answer (score 1):

In TexMaker, there are two ways I currently implement autocompletion of `\left(•\right)` with the cursor correctly positioned at the •, so that I don't need to use arrow keys or the mouse:

**Method 1**

Go to `User -> User Tags -> Edit User Tags`.

A dialog box will pop up. Select which shortcut combination you want. The default runs from Shift+F1 to Shift +F10

Under `Menu Item`, label it whatever you want. This just names the shortcut.

Under `Latex Content`, enter `\left(@\right)`

Click OK

Now press Shift+F1 (or whatever you chose) and it will auto-insert `\left(•\right)` with • immediately highlighted - like how autocomplete of commands with placeholder arguments work, such as `\mathrm{•}`. The next keystroke will replace •

**Method 2**

Go to `User -> Customize Completion`.

Enter `\left(@\right)` and click Add

This lists `\left(•\right)` directly after `\left(` in the autocompletion list, so it requires one additional keystroke (down arrow key) to select it. Not my favourite because I am lazy