# Equations: Using brackets across "align" command

Tags: equations, align, brackets

I have a lengthy function that is messing up:

```
\begin{align*}
D(a,z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}2^{\frac{a}{2}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{4}} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\Upgamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right) \ {_1F_1}\left(-\frac{a}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right) \\
 &+ \sqrt{2}z\sin \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\Upgamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right) \ {_1F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right) \right)
\end{align*}
```

The last bracket `\right)` is not showing up. I think this is because I broke the lines in the middle at `&+`. Rather than splitting up the function into another set with the term right next to `D(a,z)=`, would it be possible to get this bracket working? I'm sure it would, I just don't know how.

[image: Equation]

Thanks!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173771/15925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pair `left` and `right` on two separate lines.
Just use `\left( … \right.` and `\left. … \right)`.

You can also use `\Bigg`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    With \verb|\left( … \right.| and \verb|\left. … \right)|
    \begin{align*}
    D(a,z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}2^{\frac{a}{2}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{4}} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right) \ {_1F_1}\left(-\frac{a}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\right.\\
    &\left.+ \sqrt{2}z\sin \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right) \ {_1F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right) \right)
    \end{align*}

    With \verb|\Biggl( …\Biggr)|
    \begin{align*}
    D(a,z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}2^{\frac{a}{2}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{4}} \Biggl(\cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right) \ {_1F_1}\left(-\frac{a}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\\
    &+ \sqrt{2}z\sin \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right) \ {_1F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{2}\right) \Biggr)
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

*I use `\Gamma` instead of `\Upgamma`*

[image]

Comment: Using `\left( ... \right. ... \left. ... \right)` is generally not advisable as you'll easily end up with `()` of different sizes. Manual scaling is better.