# How to make \{ and \} automatically have \left and \right

Tags: macros, brackets

## Desired behavior

`\{` and `\}` should turn into `\left\{` and `\right\{`.

## Attempt 1

```tex
\edef\{{\left\{}
\edef\}{\right\}}
```

### Error message

```tex
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\font@name ->
             \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 
l.16 \edef\{{\left\{
                    }
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

## Attempt 2

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\edef\{{\left\string{}
\edef\}{\right\string}}

\begin{document}
$\{\}$
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: – ̋]

### Error message

```tex
Missing delimiter (. inserted).

<to be read again> 
                   {
l.7 $\{
       \}$
I was expecting to see something like `(' or `\{' or
`\}' here. If you typed, e.g., `{' instead of `\{', you
should probably delete the `{' by typing `1' now, so that
braces don't get unbalanced. Otherwise just proceed.
Acceptable delimiters are characters whose \delcode is
nonnegative, or you can use `\delimiter <delimiter code>'.

! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.7 $\{\}
         $
I was expecting to see something like `(' or `\{' or
`\}' here. If you typed, e.g., `{' instead of `\{', you
should probably delete the `{' by typing `1' now, so that
braces don't get unbalanced. Otherwise just proceed.
Acceptable delimiters are characters whose \delcode is
nonnegative, or you can use `\delimiter <delimiter code>'.
```

## Attempt 3

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\edef\{{\left\string\{}
\edef\}{\right\string\}}

\begin{document}
$\{\}$
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: \–\ ̋]

## Related, working solutions

Doing this for `\langle` and `\rangle` works just fine:

```tex
\edef\langle{\left\langle}
\edef\rangle{\right\rangle}
```

Even doing this for `(` and `)` is a bit more complicated, but works:

```tex
\begingroup
    \catcode`(\active
    \xdef({\left\string(}
    \catcode`)\active
    \xdef){\right\string)}
\endgroup
\mathcode`(="8000
\mathcode`)="8000
```

Comment: Of course this can be done, but it's not really a good idea.  See [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173740).

Comment: You could use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` to define `\braced{{x_i}^2}`.

Comment: @Davislor True. It's still messier than just `\{x_i^2\}`, IMO.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I would strongly advise against redefining standard TeX syntax to mean something different. First, it makes the code impossible to read because the syntax means something different from what anyone reading it thinks it does. Second, any code you copy-and-paste to a new document or a new template will silently break. Third, you disable the ability to control the sizing of your braces if you want to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual trick is to `\let` the old command to an "orig" version and use it in the definition of a changed command:

```
\let\leftbraceOrig=\{
\let\rightbraceOrig=\}
\def\{{\left\leftbraceOrig}
\def\}{\right\rightbraceOrig}
```

Result:

```
\begin{equation}
\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2} dx \}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really. You break usage of `\{` and `\}` in text mode.

Comment: I stand corrected

Answer (score 12):

It's a very bad idea, really. See [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/4427)

However, we can find the definitions of `\{` and `\}` in `latex.ltx` and see

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\}}{\ifmmode\rbrace\else\textbraceright\fi}
```

so it's quite simple: add

```latex
\let\{\relax \let\}\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\left\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\}}{\ifmmode\right\rbrace\else\textbraceright\fi}
```

to your document preamble. The first line is to avoid warnings about the redefinition. This still allows using `\{` and `\}` in text mode (without `\left` and `\right`, of course, which wouldn't make sense in that context).

Much better is to load `mathtools` and do

```latex
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\braces}{\{}{\}}
```

so you can do

```latex
\braces{x} \braces[\big]{x} \braces[\Big]{x} \braces[\bigg]{x} \braces[\Bigg]{x}
```

for manual size selection of

```latex
\braces*{x}
```

for automatic size selection.

### Your attempts

#### Attempt 1

For `\edef\{{\left\{}` we need to check the various expansion steps. The first level expansion of `\{` is

```latex
\x@protect\{\protect\{•
```

(the bullet stands for a space in the control sequence name). The next expansion step is

```latex
\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\else\@x@protect\{\fi\protect\{•
```

In the document preamble, `\protect` *is* the same as `\@typeset@protect` (both are `\relax`), so the true branch is followed, yielding nothing, so you end up with

```latex
\protect\{•
```

that becomes

```latex
\protect\ifmmode \lbrace \else \textbraceleft \fi
```

(because `\protect` is not expandable). Since you are *not* in math mode, the false branch is followed, leading to

```latex
\protect\textbraceleft
```

(there should be a trailing `\fi`, but that's eventually disappearing, because `\edef` does full expansion). It's not finished, yet, because we need to know what `\textbraceleft` does. We get

```latex
\protect\OMS-cmd \textbraceleft \OMS\textbraceleft
```

Oh, well, what's this? `\OMS-cmd` is something that should never appear inside an `\edef`, because it wants to perform assignments.

You're doomed.

#### Attempt 2

Your `\edef\{{\left\string{}` defines `\{` to be `\left{` (where the brace is turned into a “printable character”). This is illegal, because `{` as a printable character has its `\delcode` set to −1, so you get a “missing delimiter” error at `\{`.

#### Attempt 3

With `\edef\{{\left\string\{}` you get a puzzling output. You are actually applying `\left` to a backslash of category code 12 and this *has* a positive `\delcode`, namely `"26E30F` meaning that character `"6E` from math family 2 is used if no sizing is needed (the symbol font has indeed a backslash there) or character `"0F` from math family 3 otherwise (and again you get a backslash). The left brace tells TeX to print use the math code `"007B`, so the character in slot `"7B` from math family 0, which is the ordinary text font and contains the en-dash at that slot.

#### Why does `\edef\langle{\left\langle}` work?

Because `\langle` is defined in a very different way: its definition is

```latex
\delimiter"426830A
```

(with a space at the end) and so the `\edef` just does the same as

```latex
\def\langle{\left\delimiter"426830A }
```

because the expansion of `\langle` consists of unexpandable tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanations! Unless I'm mistaken, your last line should read `\def\langle{\left\delimiter"426830A }` (note the space) because `\langle` is defined by `\def\langle{\delimiter"426830A }` in order to make sure the 〈number〉 is finished. Unrelated: you might want to add to your explanations that `\left` and `\delimiter` are unexpandable (I can do it in an edit if you prefer).

Comment: @frougon Yes, there should be a space at the end.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for the esaustive answer. Is it possibile to define similar macros for round brackets and square brackets? Right now I'm looking for definitions of `(`, `)`, `[` and `]` in `latex.ltx` but it's a very long file and I don't know exactly what to look for.

Answer (score 4):

The cause of your problem is that LaTeX defines `\{` as `\ifmmode\lbrace \else\textbraceleft\fi`. If you are using LaTeX then your `\edef` goes to the branch `\textbraceleft`.

But you can define:

```
\edef\{{\left\lbrace}
\edef\}{\right\rbrace}
```