# Macros to make [ ] and ( ) automatically have \mleft and \mright

Tags: math-mode, macros

Since I'm writing a document with thousands of brackets of all kinds, manually sizing all the brackets or manually add `\mleft` and `\mright` every time will be need a lot of time in the end. Moreover, I don't have strict typographic rules to follow since the document is for private use.

So in this case it is not a bad idea to redefine `(` and `)` as `\mleft(` and `\mright)` respectively, and the same also for square and curly brackets (obviously in math mode only).

I'm aware about all the drawbacks about the use of auto resizing brackets (for example [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right)  or [Why doesn't LaTeX interpret ( as \left( and ) as \right)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141858/why-doesnt-latex-interpret-as-left-and-as-right) or [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right)), at least using `\mleft` and `\right` the spacing problem is solved.

In the page [How to make \{ and \} automatically have \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492904/how-to-make-and-automatically-have-left-and-right) egreg explains that there is an easy way to achieve the goal in the case of curly brackets. The macro consists in adding `\left` and `\right` in the definitions of `\{` and `\}` that are found in `latex.ltx` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\let\{\relax \let\}\relax % to avoid warnings about the redefinition
\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\mleft\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\}}{\ifmmode\mright\rbrace\else\textbraceright\fi}

\begin{document}
$a\{\dfrac13\}a$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm looking for a similar way to redefine the commands of curved and square brackets, but I don't know how to find their definitions in the file `latex.ltx` since it is a very big file.

Comment: Well, they are not macros, but are defined as delimiters, see lines 162-164 of `fontmath.ltx`.

Comment: In my opinion, this is more of a problem for your editor…

Comment: You might be interested in the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter, and its variants,  command from `mathtools`.

Comment: The package `physics` provides automatic bracing option. But the opening bracket has to be preceeded by a function (`\abs`, `\sin`, ..) or you have to use `\qty`. Closing bracket will be automatically paired and adjusted. See 2nd page of the [manual](http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf)

Comment: the `\{` redefinition will break any existing use of `\left\{x\right\}`  which occurs in multiple packages, if not in your document, there are really only downsides to this.

Comment: The `nath` package does it by default, but `nath` display math clashes with `amsmath`, so it doesn't tend to be used much.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks could you explain a bit more what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make these symbols math active by setting their mathcode to 8000 and then define them by the lowercase trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\makeatletter
\def\@mathactive#1#2{\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`#1
    \lowercase{\endgroup
        \def~{#2}}%
    \mathcode`#1="8000\relax}

\@mathactive({\mleft(}
\@mathactive){\mright)}
% Do the same for brackets. (Do not try it with braces.)
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$ (\dfrac12) $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Here is a code that works with PDFTeX. In PDFTeX, AMSMath seems to have a problem with active math chars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begingroup
\catcode`\(=\active
\catcode`\)=\active
\gdef({\mleft\lparen}
\gdef){\mright\rparen}
\endgroup

\def\lparen{\delimiter"028300\relax}
\def\rparen{\delimiter"029301\relax}

\everymath{\mathcode`\(="8000
           \mathcode`\)="8000}
\everydisplay{\mathcode`\(="8000
              \mathcode`\)="8000}

\begin{document}

$ (\dfrac12) $

\[ (\frac18) \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I took LuaTeX. Sorry for not mentioning this.

Comment: I have added a version that works with PDFTeX.

Comment: `amsmath` has no problem with active characters but has (see line 679) `\mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\(\relax`, which of course cannot work. But +1 anyway, even if I wouldn't recommend this even under torture `:-)`

Comment: Erm, I don't know how to get a backquote in code between backquotes... `:-/`

Comment: I argree with you, I do not recommend this, too. But it is an answer to the question. :D

Comment: I use this solution to make my TeX files more readable, example `\@mathactive√\sqrt`, so i can write `$√{100}$`instead of `$\sqrt{100}$`. And in PlainTeX you can make super- and subscripts active, so that you can write `$x²³$` instead of `$x^{23}$` as it is possible in Lua/XeLaTeX with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You will see if you try to compile the first MWE with PDFLaTeX. ;)