# How a program a command which counts the delimiter within itself and alternates brackets accordingly?

Tags: delimiters

Is it possible to define a command which defines a delimiter which alternates round, square, brackets brackets in the formulas?

The command would count if it has other 'mydelimiter' within itselft and alternate for better readability.

```
$x = \left\mydelimiter \left\mydelimiter  a+b \right\mydelimiter *y \right\mydelimiter / z $
```

would produce x = [(a+b)*y] / z

Thanks for your help.

Comment: would be much easier if you changed the syntax to, say `$x = \\myleft \myleft  a+b \myright *y \myright / z $` (`left` and `\right` are delicate beasts)

Comment: however the supplied expression would look better without `\left` and `\right`  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach than David's allows you to cycle through more than two types of parentheses and also works with `\left` and `\right`. (Do consider the warnings regarding the use of `\left` and `\right`, though. The [`mleftright`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package may be interesting regarding this.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \newcount\mydelim@level
    \def\@ldlm#1{%
        \ifcase\numexpr #1\relax
            (%
        \or [%
        \or \{%
        \else
            \@ldlm{#1-3}%
        \fi
    }
    \def\@rdlm#1{%
        \ifcase\numexpr #1\relax
            \GenericWarning{}{LaTeX Warning: You used a \string\rdlm with no matching \string\ldlm!}{}{}%
        \or )%
        \or ]%
        \or \}%
        \else
            \@rdlm{#1-3}%
        \fi
    }
    \def\ldlm{%
        \@ldlm{\mydelim@level}%
        \global\advance\mydelim@level 1\relax
    }
    \def\rdlm{%
        \@rdlm{\mydelim@level}%
        \global\advance\mydelim@level -1\relax
    }

\begin{document}

\[
    \left\ldlm\left\ldlm\left\ldlm\left\ldlm
    \sum x_i
    \right\rdlm\right\rdlm\right\rdlm\right\rdlm
\]

\[
    \ldlm\ldlm\ldlm\ldlm x\rdlm\rdlm\rdlm\rdlm
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: thk for your answer, it is possible for the most inner bracket to always be a round bracket? i.e. whether i have 2, 3, ... N brackets, they are always selected in the order '(', '[', '{', '(' from most inner bracket to most outter bracket so that the pattern to identify bracket hierarchy is the same.

Comment: @stackoverflower You could, but you would have to use the `aux` file and compile twice, as TeX can't know how many brackets you will nest at the start. Search around for how to do this or ask a new question. (I won't have time to look at this myself in the near future.)

Answer (score 2):

The nesting count would not be the hard part with the suggested syntax but arranging for `\mydelimiter` to swap between open and close delimiter depending on being prefixed by `\left` or `\right` would probably involve redefining the `\left` and `\right` primitives and have bad consequences somewhere..

So here is the same idea with a modified syntax that is simpler to use and a lot simpler to implement.

As noted in comments using `\left` `\right` in these cases is not always optimal and introduces additional horizontal space even when the delimiters are not enlarged.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ldelim{[}
\def\rdelim{]}
\def\zlefts{\left[\def\zright{\right]}\let\zleft\zleftr}
\def\zleftr{\left(\def\zright{\right)}\let\zleft\zlefts}

\let\zleft\zlefts


\begin{document}

$x = \zleft \zleft  a+b \zright * y \zright / z $


$x = [(  a+b ) * y ] / z $
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `enparen` package can automatically alternate the delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enparen} 
\begin{document}
$x = \enparen{\enparen{ a+b } * y } / z $
 \end{document}
```

[image]