# Is there any command inverse to \mathstrut?

Tags: spacing, delimiters

Maybe my question is a bit ridiculous but I wonder is there any command inverse to `\mathstrut`? I think this command would be useful for reducing unwanted size of auto delimiter such as inline `\Set{}`

```
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
some text
$\Set{A\in R| A\in Q}$ %a bit bad delimiter 
\end{document}
```

or in `\left \right` math formulas.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, not horizontally, reducing vertical size. are you familiar with `\mathstrut`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `\smash`?

Comment: How to use it? e.g. `\Set{\smash[b]{A\in R| A\in Q}}`? but this produce some error for me!!

Comment: In a sense `\smash{...}` is the opposite, making its contents zero height and depth.  In the braket package's command `\Set` you would have to `\smash` each half by itself.  But in your example the braces are already the smallest braket will use.  For me the `mathtools` approach to a set command is preferable.

Comment: To use `\smash` here write `\Set{\smash{A\in R}|\smash{A\in Q}}`

Comment: aha..! its error is because of `|`? Thank you.

Comment: There is a non auto scaling version in the manual for the mathtools package. Having it go auto scaling by default is seldom a good idea

Comment: @daleif That is partly what I meant, avoid the automatic scaling.  But the `mathtools` documentation defines `\Set` with its `\Set*` variant which is auto scaling

Comment: Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann yes, but you have to choose the star to get auto scaling it is not the default.

Comment: The simplest is *not* using `\Set` from `braket`. There's no reason to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\smash` to hide height and depth of contents.  In the context of the `\Set` command from the `braket` package you need to apply this to each half of the contents separately.  In your particular example you will see no difference (with standard fonts) as the braces are already at their smallest size.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

$\Set{A\in R|A\in Q}$

$\Set{\smash{A\in R}|\smash{A\in Q}}$

$\Set{A\in R^{2}|A\in Q}$

$\Set{\smash{A\in R^{2}}|\smash{A\in Q}}$

\end{document}
```

In general it is best to avoid auto sizing, cf. [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/15925) .  The `mathtools` package documentation provides a `\Set` command that can be manually sized, e.g. `\Set[\bigg]`, with an auto sizing variant `\Set*`.  Here is the version I usually use:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\with}{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
\newcommand{\SetSymbol}[1][]{\nonscript\:#1\vert
  \allowbreak\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Set}[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{#1}

\begin{document}

\( \Set{A\in R \with A\in Q} \)

\( \Set{A\in R^{2} \with A\in Q} \)

\( \Set[\big]{A\in R^{2} \with A\in Q} \)

\( \Set*{A\in R^{2} \with A\in Q} \)

\end{document}
```

You write `\with` instead of the `|` in the `braket` notation.  It has the advantage over `braket` that if you change your mind later and wish to have the separator as a colon instead of a vertical line, then you just adjust the definition of `\with` (or of `\SetSymbol`).

Comment: is this works for command defined in preamble using `\left` and `\right`? e.g. `\newcommand[\norm][1]{\left\| #1\right\|}` then `$\norm{\smash{(A^2)^2}}$`?

Comment: Yes, but again I would use the `mathtools` constraction `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}` which provides `\norm[\big]` etc. and  the autoscaling `\norm*`.  Autoscaling is really only for drafting of material.

Comment: @C.F.G note for example that your norm definition is wrong if you remove the `\left/right` part, try removing them at do `\norm{-1}`, the spacing on the `-` is wrong. In Andrews version the spacing is correct (mainly because of the use of `\lVert` and `\rVert` (in general `\|` is not the correct symbol to use for norms).