# How to know when to use \left( and \right) and when not to?

Tags: best-practices, brackets

How to decide when `\left(` and `\right)` are necessary?

Here is my code that shows various ways to format the same formulae:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Example 1.1:
\[
    \frac12 \left( p + \frac{((a + b)^2 + c)^2}{2} \right)
\]

Example 1.2:
\[
    \frac12 \left( p + \frac{\left( (a + b)^2 + c \right)^2}{2} \right)
\]

Example 1.3:
\[
    \frac12 \left( p + \frac{\left( \left( a + b \right)^2 + c \right)^2}{2} \right)
\]

Example 2.1:
\[
    \frac12 \left( p + \frac{((a + b)^2 + \frac12)^2}{2} \right)
\]

Example 2.2:
\[
    \frac12 \left( p + \frac{\left( (a + b)^2 + \frac12 \right)^2}{2} \right)
\]

Example 2.3:
\[
    \frac12 \left( p + \frac{\left( \left( a + b \right)^2 + \frac12 \right)^2}{2} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Among examples 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3, is there a preferred format?

Among examples 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3, is there a preferred format?

How do you decide when we need to employ `\left(` and `\right)` to format formulas? Is it just a matter of taste or are there any typography rules for it?

Comment: In this particular case, probably the best way to typeset is `\frac{1}{2} \biggl( p + \frac{\bigl( (a + b)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \bigr)^2}{2} \biggr)` or `\frac{1}{2} \biggl( p + \frac{\bigl( (a + b)^2 + 1/2 \bigr)^2}{2} \biggr)`; that is, not a single `\left...\right` pair…

Comment: A general guideline: Use `\left...\right` for “genuinely large” blocks of maths (matrices, for example). Try to use `\bigl`, `\bigr`, etc. based on the hierarchy of the nested parenthesized expressions (and to gain complete control on how large the delimiters should grow). This is indeed “just a matter of taste”, but there are good and bad taste. Also, it depends on the journal/editor style…

Comment: IMHO in case 2.x `\frac {1} {4} \bigl( 2p +.... ` and getting rid of the inner fraction  leads to a much more readable thing, unless you want to highlight that `p +... ` thing. Basically, the best way to typeset a math formula depends on the context, and where you want to out the accent... Including brackets' size.

Comment: _please_ write `\frac{1}{2}` !!

Comment: this is probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740  I wouldn't use left/right in this display at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is `\frac12` incorrect or is it bad coding convention?

Comment: @LoneLearner the latex syntax as specified in the latex book says the braces (for all commands) are mandatory.  When using tex you can drop them but it looks weird/horrible if done with a command like frac that can take arbitrary content (it's OK with commands that can only take a single token,`\setlength\textwidth{..}` instead of `\setlength{\textwidth}{...}` but as it essentially is only happening due to low level parsing rules, it will often fail in latex2xx convertors eg conversion to html, as they do not have a full tex parser and normally expect some reasonable markup for the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get yourself to replace all (direct or indirect) instances of `\frac12` with `0.5`, some obvious ways arise to display both terms much more compactly and -- I would argue -- more legibly. I will call these ways "Example 1.4" and "Example 2.4", respectively. Observe that they employ `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right` for improved, i.e., more-compact spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright} % for \mleft and \mright macros
\begin{document}
Example 1.4:\quad $0.5 \mleft( p + 0.5[ (a+b)^2 + c ]^2 \mright)$

\bigskip
Example 2.4:\quad $0.5 \mleft( p + 0.5[ (a+b)^2 + 0.5 ]^2 \mright)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: usually (for different reasons) in mathematics I have been involved in, 0.5 and 1/2 aren't the same thing:-)