# Problem with formatting expectation using a command

Tags: macros, delimiters, amssymb

Here's the minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\bbE}[1][X]{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\right]}

\begin{document}

Working:
$\bbE[XY]$

Broken:
$\bbE[\bbE[X]] \bbE[\bbE[Y]]$

\end{document}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Missing delimiter (. inserted).

[image: Example]

Comment: Use braces around the argument: `\bbE[{\bbE[X]}]`.  But you don't need (and likely shouldn't) use `\left...\right` for single symbols like `X` and `Y`, so you could simplify your command to `\newcommand{\bbE}{\mathbb{E}}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik what is the reason not to use `\left...\right` for single symbols? when I actually use this I have expectations of sums and larger things

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik also, braces around any combination of arguments didn't fix the issue

Comment: @campa thanks, I think this explains why I'm having the issue

Comment: @reuzed It gets spacing wrong around the parentheses.  Compare `$x(1+2)x$` with `$x\left(1+2\right)x$`.  Also `\left...\right` encloses the subformula in a box, so line breaking can't happen if needed.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/134574).  Regardless, that's best practices but not what's causing you the error.  The error is due to how LaTeX grabs the optional argument, and adding braces like in `\bbE[{\bbE[X]}]` _does_ solve the problem (which is what the post campa linked says)

Comment: Easy fix: replace your command definition by `\NewDocumentCommand\bbE{O{X}}{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\right]}`.  Commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` auto-match the delimiters, so you can nest them

Answer (score 1):

Another fix:

While latex is looking for the optional argument of the outer command stop (`]`) it finds the square bracket of the second (inner) command and stops there... This is happening because it works with similar way of my first definitions (see `\def` commands) that contains something like `\@ifnextchar[` and ends at the first `]` ... By defining the `\@lp` (left square bracket) and `\@rp` commands it will not supposed as closed parenthesis in the first read from latex but will expand to it after that and this will solve the confusion with the optional argument of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\def\@lp{[}
\def\@rp{]}
\def\bbE{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@bbeWith}%
{\@bbeWithout}%
}
\def\@bbeWith[#1]{\mathbb{E}\left\@lp#1\right\@rp}
\def\@bbeWithout{\mathbb{E}\left\@lp X\right\@rp}

%or
%\renewcommand{\bbE}[1][X]{\mathbb{E}\left\@lp#1\right\@rp}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Working:
$\bbE[XY]$

Broken:
$\bbE[\bbE[X]] \bbE[\bbE[Y]]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! could you briefly explain how this works?

Comment: Please take a look to the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use the features of `xparse` that is good in these cases and doesn't require further tricks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand{\expec}{O{X}}{\mathbb{E}[#1]}
%\newcommand{\bbE}[1][X]{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\right]}

\begin{document}

Working:
$\expec[XY]$

Working:
$\expec[\expec[X]]$ and $\expec[\expec[Y]]$

\end{document}
```

You may need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` if you're not running an up-to-date LaTeX distribution.

I used a more semantic name, feel free to use the name of your choice.

[image]