# Parenthesis redefinition

Tags: shortcut

Is it possible to redefine the left and right parenthesis (or define new parentheses in the form of a shortcut) in such a way that the character "(" to be equivalent with "\left (" and the character ")" to be equlvalent with "\right )"? This would be very helpfull, since we can save a lot of typing.

Comment: That is, assuming that you always want `\left(` and `\right)`, which is very disputable.

Comment: You could create shorter macros, like \lp and \rp.   but generally we try to discourage the overuse of \left and \right.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/1090