# Should I apply \left and \right to all the parentheses and brackets?

Tags: equations, alignment

We know that we don't need to write `f\left(x\right)` instead of `f(x)`

But when you deal with something(that contains fraction, sum or int) like `f(a+i\dfrac{b-a}{n})`, you have to change it to left-right alignment form like `f\left(a+i\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right)`

So now imagine there are **thousands of** formulas like I described above in a large LaTeX document(only formulas and no packages). If you check one by one and correct the latter one into left-right alignment, it will take you a lot of time. **Is it ok to make all the parentheses and brackets into left-right alignment in such a document(by using regex)?**

Comment: In general, raising brackets are applied for fraction, sum and int, etc. symbols comes and for matrices, etc.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yes, I know. I just give an example.

Comment: Are you familiar with the posting [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) I'd say that the premise in your claim that "... you have to change it to left-right alignment form" is wrong: In addition to `\left` and `\right`, there is also `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, and `\Biggl` along with `\bigr`, `\Bigr`, `\biggr`, and `\Biggr`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! "Is it ok..." <- You are the one who decides what is OK for your document. Others can only give advice, and my guess is that there will mainly be advice against.

Comment: in your first sentence you say you don't need left right in f(X) but more than that, it is wrong to use it as it gives unneeded horizontal space