Locally delete ^ and _ in braces
I want to delete ^ and _ in a braces like \left( and \right) so that size change of braces ignores super and subscripts.
I want to define it as a macro, but use of xstring package does not allow me to make macros using \StrDel or similar commands.
Any suggestions?
Edit:
I want a macro that converts the following
\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt 

to
\int 0 \infty t {z-1} e {-t} dt 

or
\int t e dt 


Do you want to delete the ^ and _ only or also their arguments? Please also add a minimal working example to your question to clarify your question.

I am quite sure that the best way would be not to use \left and \right. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/82917.

Please clarify what you mean by "delete ^ and _". E.g., should x^{6} be treated as x6 or as x?

Either will work, because I just want the height of $x$ in case of $x^6$.

Would it be okay if the result just makes _ into the underscore character, instead of killing it completely? I am thinking along the lines of this answer.

I’ll remove the downvote when you’ll explain clearly what you want to do, because the current edit adds nothing.

@egreg probably poormans nath

@WillieWong I think this is a good solution, to convert $_$ into a normal underscore character. How is it accomplished in that answer?

@Joseph it is done by changing category codes. But almost certainly what you are facing is an XY Problem: you are likely to get a much better answer if you tell us, ultimately, what you hope to accomplish, instead of asking us to help you fix your attempted solution. For example, for auto-scaling parentheses that ignore the super/subscripts, you can use the nath package; but beware: it is incompatible with a lot of other math packages.

One option is to do a little bit of catcode play that locally turns ^ and _ into active characters, and define the corresponding actions to be \@gobble. This way superscripts and subscripts will be removed.
I do not guarantee that the following proof of concept is bug-free or works beyond the MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\^ 
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\@gobble 
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\@gobble
\makeatother
\def\flattensupsubs{\begingroup \catcode`_=\active \catcode`^=\active \doflattensupsubs}
\def\doflattensupsubs#1{\scantokens{#1\empty}\endgroup}
\newcommand*\enParen[1]{\left( \vphantom{\flattensupsubs{#1}} \smash{#1} \right)}

\begin{document}
\[ \left( \int_{\frac12}^{a^b} G_0 x^3 ~dx \right), \enParen{ \int_{\frac12}^{a^b} G_0 x^3 ~dx}, \left(\flattensupsubs{ \int_{\frac12}^{a^b} G_0 x^3 ~dx}\right). \]
\end{document}



Explanation of the code for newcomers:
\makeatletter: see What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?
The \lccode and \lowercase trick: read first The \lowercase trick and What are category codes?
The key idea is that TeX treats each character as a pair (cat, char). The character code char is the value of the ASCII representation of the character, and the category code cat has some default values for each character, but can be changed on the fly if necessary. Each pair (cat, char) is allowed to have a different meaning. So the same character when used in contexts that assign them different category codes can mean different things.
Basically, the line with \lccode pretends that the character ~ has a lowercase counterpart that is ^ (or _). But since ~ is an active character (determined by category code), this lowercase counterpart would also be an active character. We can then assign it a meaning (as a macro); here we let it be equal to \@gobble which is the macro that eats up its argument and does nothing else.
Which means that we have two possible meanings for ^: normally it is a category code 7, which means that it denotes superscripts in mathematics. But if we are in a context where ^ is an active character (category code 13), it can be replaced by the macro \@gobble.
The \flattensupsubs macro enters a group where we locally changed the category codes of ^ and _ from their defaults (7 and 8) to active (13). So within this group, if TeX parses ^ and _ the active definition will be used, resulting in the removal of the superscripts and subscripts.
Caveat The interpretation of a character into the (cat, char) pair happens when TeX parses the input. So if you do something like
\def\preint{\int_a^b}
\[ \enParen{\preint} \]

it will not "work", because the only parsing that TeX is doing is parsing the string \preint which does not involve itself _ or ^, and when \preint was defined the category codes of _ and ^ are their default values.

The OP also requested to deal with the ', which is a math-active character that expands essentially to ^{\prime}. The same trick will not work above, since redefining the active meaning of ' will break things everywhere. But the fact that ' is already active in math means we can just redefine it. Here, we will use a more standard approach for conditionally turning on and off the effect of a macro, by installing a boolean flag which gets set by the \flattensupsubs macro. MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\^
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\@gobble
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\@gobble
\newif\ifflattenprime
\flattenprimefalse
{\catcode`\'=\active \gdef'{\ifflattenprime\else\expandafter\active@math@prime\fi}}
\def\flattensupsubs{\begingroup \flattenprimetrue\catcode`_=\active \catcode`^=\active \doflattensupsubs}
\def\doflattensupsubs#1{\scantokens{#1\empty}\endgroup}
\newcommand*\enParen[1]{\left( \vphantom{\flattensupsubs{#1}} \smash{#1} \right)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \left( \int_{\frac12}^{a^b} G_0'' x^3 ~dx \right), \enParen{ \int_{\frac12}^{a^b} G_0'' x^3 ~dx}, \left(\flattensupsubs{ \int_{\frac12}^{a^b} G_0'' x^3 ~dx}\right). \]

\end{document}


Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. Since when I put your code inside my preamble it deletes all the hats and subscripts in my paper, I put it in a box in the definition of my code and it worked. Also thank you for your very kind instructions!

Can I erase $'$ in the same manner?

Unfortunately, no. The prime symbol ' is already math active, so the exact same method will break things everywhere. Instead, one can install a toggle, see my edit.
