How to enter curly brace "{" as text in LaTex
In Wolfram Mathematica a 2x2 matrix can be entered with:
matrix1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
I want to capture this Mathematica specific notation in an LaTex document using Overleaf (that I may print out for reference later)
When I enter "matrix1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}" in the code editor window of Overleaf LaTex the output in the PDF is:
matrix1 = a, b, c, d
That is, the curly braces disappear.
How can I get Overleaf LaTex to output the curly braces in "matrix1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}" to the PDF?

\( \mathit{matrix}_1={ {a,b}, {c,d} } \)

You might use \{ and \}, but I think that a better alternative is to use listings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\newcommand{\Wcode}{\lstinline[language=Mathematica]}

\begin{document}

With math mode
\[
\mathrm{matrix1}=\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}
\]
or possibly better
\begin{center}
\Wcode|matrix1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}}|
\end{center}

\end{document}



If you want to make the braces scale based on the size of content inside, use \left\{ and \right\}

@invalidsyntax_ But read through https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/107497 before using \left and \right.
