# How can I do this equation?

Tags: equations

I'm new using latex, someone can help mw with this equation, please 
How can I do this equation?

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this question should be helpful: [Math symbol question: Vertical bar for ''evaluated at …''](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40160/579)

Comment: Exactly as @barbarabeeton says. The fraction (assuming that's giving you difficulties) is `$\frac{\delta T_{i}}{\delta D}$` (obviously the vertical line and the Q should also be within that same pair of `$ ... $`)

Comment: Thanks, the vertical bar was my problem. I didn't know the comand big. 
This is the code $\frac{\delta T_{i}}{\delta D} \big|_{q}$

Answer (score 2):

Hello welcome to the community. 
There are a couple ways to do this, I think the easiest and most universal (if you plan on adjusting the sizing or environment of the math display) is the following:

```
$$
\left. \frac{\delta T_i}{\delta D} \right|_Q
$$
```

[image: Latex Output]

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)