# Spacing around divide (|) symbol

Tags: math-mode, spacing

LaTex by default sets fairly small spaces around "divide" symbol (`|`). Is there a way to force larger skip (e. g. force LaTex to treat `|` as binary operator or `=` symbol)?
MWE would be fairly simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
What is set by default:

$a|b$

What I want:

$a\hspace{0.28em}|\hspace{0.28em}b$ %for some reason I can't use mu in \hspace, but 1mu=1/18 em and 0.28em=5mu=\thickmuskip.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mid` is what you want.  `$a\mid b$`

Comment: You may check this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40160/math-symbol-question-vertical-bar-for-evaluated-at

Comment: By default, LaTeX inserts no whitespace at all around the `|` symbol.  In contrast, if you employ the macro `\mid`, LaTeX inserts a thickspace -- as is appropriate for a *relational* operator -- around the vertical bar.

Comment: This might also be interesting: [\mid, | (vertical bar), \vert, \lvert, \rvert, \divides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498/82917).

Comment: The `|` symbol is most commonly used for absolute values, as in `|x|`, where no extra spaces are desired.