# What is the "pipe" for boundaries in integration and how can I represent it in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

When doing integration, I was taught to add a bar next to an antiderivative to show the bounds if it was a definite integral:

[image]

`3x|^3_0` is a nice approximation but this doesn't work for larger equations.

What is this symbol and how can I generate it in LaTeX?

Comment: Do any of the answers here help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216408/evaluation-symbol-consistent-implementation or here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40160/math-symbol-question-vertical-bar-for-evaluated-at

Comment: You can use , say `$3x\bigg|_0^3$`

Comment: Actaully, maybe this one is better: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294499/evaluated-at-bar-for-derivatives-bigr-biggr-or-left-right